# Wufoo: Your submission is missing the secure POST key

Tags: html, api, wufoo

There was a problem with your submission.

Your submission is missing the secure POST key.

when I am redirected on Wufoo then got the warning or error

I have attached screenshot related error

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <form name="Wufoo Button" accept-charset="UTF-8"
                enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
action="https://subdomainname.wufoo.com/forms/sponsorchild/">
                <!-- Dollars -->
                <input id="Field127" name="Field127" type="hidden" t-att-value="Field127" />
                <!-- Cents  -->
                <input id="Field127-1" name="Field127-1" type="hidden" t-att-value="Field1271" />
                <!-- Child name and file number -->
                <input id="Field125" name="Field125" type="hidden" t-att-value="Field125" />
                <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code, to get a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Or - should there be private API keys involved - at least provide some more information to the API.

Comment: @dennlinger can you please check it, i used simple HTML form

Comment: I suggest removing the Python tag, unless there is something hat you might want to add to the question. I'm afraid I can't really help you with HTML too much, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still stuck on this but I found the answer.

You need to keep this bit of HTML at the end of the form (you can just hide it with css). The value acts as the key:

```
<li class="hide">
<label for="comment">Do Not Fill This Out</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="idstamp" name="idstamp" value="[WUFOO VALUE IS HERE]" />
</li>
```